# Should I use Developer Entity or User Entity?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

which type of entities should I use in API.ai for taking the parameters value from the user? Developer Entity Or User Entity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. Both have their place depending on what you need.

Developer Entities are great if your conversations have parts that you can narrow down as you design it. So, for example, if you only have a few types of music in your system and you want the user to say "Play some Jazz" or "I want to hear Broadway classics", then you can define "Jazz" and "Broadway classics" as Developer Entities as you define your Intents.

User Entities, however, are really powerful if you have user accounts and you want Users to have access to their own elements. An example of this is if they have their own music (and just their own music) available on the system - when they logged in, you could set the User Entity to the values of the names of their music. **The system would then try to match just their possible values and not possibly match some other, similar, music that is not theirs.**

Developer Entities can be set up front as you define them as you define your Intents. User Entities are set once the conversation has begun using API.AI's API.

Most of the time you will probably use a Developer (or System) Entity, but when you need them, User Entities are one of API.AI's most powerful features.

Comment: Great, I like to know more is their any example for userEntity,...I have tried but didn't got how to use... It's really helpfull

Comment: If you've tried and had a problem, go ahead and open a new question, showing the problem you're having.

Comment: (Which I now see you did. {: )